# How to make elements of the list by robot framework in RED appears in autocomplete when we call the list?

Tags: collections, robotframework, keyword, robotframework-ide

I want to get an autocomplete displayed that contain elements that belongs to that list. They should appear when i call the created list by robot framework
 elements in the autocomplete list that is displayed should be the contentof the list [A,B,C,D] not just the list named [List]

```
Library    Collections    
    List 
          @{list} =    Create List   A    B    C    D
```

How to make that with robot framework ?

- Another question : can each element have a definition like keywords without being keyword but just an element from the list ?  [image]

Comment: Wha t do you mean saying "autocomplete list"?

Comment: I mean possible items in the list that i can use. Like when u search for a keyword an autocomplete list appears

Comment: You didn't make it any clear, you just re-worded your question which was unclear...

Comment: I try to update the description. I hope its clear

Comment: Why would you want list values in "autocomplete"?

Comment: In fact i have to define each test belongs to each feature i don't want to go back to requirements each time. At the end it will be included in documentation of test case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto complete functionality in RED is rather straight forward. Variables that declared in either the `*** Variables ***` section or through the declaration of keywords like `Create List` or `Create Variable`.

The difference between the autocomplete scenario's is that the one created in the `variable` section contains more information. See the two images below:

**Variable Section**
[image: Variable Section]

**Keyword Created**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what i actually mean is values of the list appear in the autocomplete list not the list itself.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with ".. appear in the autocomplete list, not the list itself .."?

Comment: I mean when i have 12 elements for example i can access to them one by one with the autocomplete suggested and not just when i put list[i] manually.

Comment: This is presently not possible. There no auto complete on dictionary content, only the variable name and this also applies to lists.

Comment: Ahh i understand know. I tried many ways but i didn't get that autocomplete. 
I hope it will be supported soon. There is no framework or some thing similar that can allow this behaviour ?

Comment: Presently there is no way to add this yourself through configuration or tinkering. The only way is modifying the actual Eclipse RED source code and develop this feature yourself.